# Distributing updates to clients using git (?)

Tags: git, updates

We have a project/product which we want to distribute to our clients.
After all build steps, the tool is basically a folder containing several executable and resource files.

Currently we distribute updates using an HTTP server, from which the client downloads new or outdated files. This has some inherent flaws (slow, no compression, no removal of file on the client after removal on the server, etc.)

Theoretically, Git would fulfill all our needs, but we would need to ship our client with an additional git client, which itselve is huge.

Do you know a better way of distributing incremental updates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would discurage git.

Beside git beeing "huge" in your opinion you will deliver the whole history. That means every clinent (also new ones) can access any older release. This *might* be something good, but usually that's not what you want.

I'd suggest to write your own update client using the existing webserver based infrastructure and taking care of the "files to remove".

Comment: Thank you, you are right on the history, that would bloat up the installation even more. Do you know, if there are any projects or tools to acomplish this? This seems like a very common problem to me